# Writing Arraylist <byte[]> to file produces invalid result (corrupt data)

Tags: c#, list, arraylist

I was testing the writing of chuncked data to a file. And I've gotten in some kind of 'trouble' I have a chuncked list of byte[] contained in an Arraylist/List. But only the List-version seems to be working. The arraylist produces a file (a wmv in this case) with an unknown codec (possibly due to corrupt data).

- Original filesize:294mb
- List filesize: 294mb
- Arraylist filesize: 304mb????? (where does that 10mb extra come from?)

No exception is thrown and i can't seem to find the origin of the problem. Could someone help me out?

Both lists recieve their data from the same stream:

```
        int chunkSize = 1024;
        byte[] chunk = new byte[chunkSize];
        using (FileStream fileReader = new FileStream(@"C:\XXXX\someMovie.wmv", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read) )
        {


            BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(fileReader);
            int bytesToRead = (int)fileReader.Length;
            do
            {
                chunk = binaryReader.ReadBytes(chunkSize);
                byteList.Add(chunk);
                bytesToRead -= chunk.Length;
            } while (bytesToRead > 0);

        }
```

The **working** List-Version `(byteList = List<byte[]>)`:

```
        using (System.IO.FileStream _FileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(@"C:\XXXX\listTest.wmv", System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < byteList.Count; i++)
            {
                _FileStream.Write(byteList[i], 0, byteList[i].Count());
            }
        }
```

The **NOT-working** Arraylist-Version `(byteList = Arraylist)`:

```
        using (System.IO.FileStream _FileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(@"C:\SIDJRGD\Zone afbakenen_2.wmv", System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < byteList.Count; i++)
            {
                _FileStream.Write(ObjectToByteArray(byteList[i]), 0, ObjectToByteArray(byteList[i]).Length);
            }
        }
```

**Function: ObjectToByteArray()** (for casting `Object` to `byte[]`)

```
private static byte[] ObjectToByteArray(Object obj)
{
    if (obj == null)
        return null;
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
    return ms.ToArray();
}
```

**Note:** I know i could just use the `List-solution` and `forget about the arraylist`. But i'm just curious what i might have done wrong....

Comment: One thing that is definitely wrong is `bytesToRead -= chunkSize;` It should be `bytesToRead -= chunk;` You have to subtract the number of bytes you actually read, not the number of bytes you wanted to read.

Comment: @MArius Bancila. Nice remark, I hadn't noticed that yet! I adjusted my code accordingly!

Comment: The problem would appear to be when you serialize your byte array, why can't you just cast your `byteList[i]` to `byte[]`?

Comment: @T.Kiley your right! When directly casting it, it does work as it should. Any idea what i've might have done wrong in my `ObjectToByteArray`?

Comment: @N55PEC Great, I'll write up an answer explaining why yours doesn't work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the `Serialize` method to convert your `Object` into a `byte[]`. The serialize method is useful for serializing anything, not just byte arrays. As a result, it packs the data in with extra meta data to allow decoding (you could deserialize that data and it would know to deserialize it into a byte array).

This extra data obviously isn't in your original byte data and as such this is corrupting the file.

You can cast the `Object` directly to a byte array. However, `List<T>` is generally preferred to `Arraylist` so I would just use `List<byte[]>`.